# Android Dagger 2 with MVP

Tags: android, dagger-2, mvp

Using Dagger 2 for the first time with MVP.

I am stuck at a very simple implementation.

my presenter module takes View Interface in constructor along with context and data manager,I am confused in how to send activity context to the constructor for the view interface..
Any help will be highly appreciated..

Here is my code for App class:

```
public class App extends Application {


    private static App app;

    public SampleComponent getSc() {
        return sc;
    }

    private SampleComponent sc;

    public static App getApp() {
        return app;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        app = this;
        sc = DaggerSampleComponent.builder()
                //.sampleModule(new SampleModule())
                .presenterModule(new PresenterModule(new MainActivity(), getApplicationContext(), new ModelManager()))
                .build();

    }
}
```

Code for Presenter Module :

```
@Module
public class PresenterModule {
    ShowCountContract.view v;
    ModelManager mm;
    Context c;
  public PresenterModule(MainActivity m, Context c,
                           ModelManager mm) {
        this.c = c;
        this.mm = mm;
        this.v = m;
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    PresenterClass getPresentationClass() {


        return new PresenterClass(mm, v);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To handle the Android context the best approach is to create an Application Component with an Application Module. This module should be responsible to provide objects that are common in the entire application, as the `Context`. And based on that component you can create subcomponents for each feature/activity/etc.

```
@Module
public class ApplicationModule {

    private final Application application;

    public ApplicationModule(Application application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    @Provides
    Context provideContext() {
        return application;
    }

}
```

If you choose to work with just one component (what I do not recommend), your code for `DaggerComponent` creation will look like this:

```
DaggerSampleComponent.builder()
        .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(this))
        .otherModule(new OtherModule())
        .build();
```

Or you can use [Component.Builder](https://proandroiddev.com/dagger-2-component-builder-1f2b91237856)

As the `Activity` instance is created by the Android Framework, we cannot pass the View interface as a constructor parameter. The common way is to create such a method as `attachView(ViewInterface)` in your Presenter to be able to set an internal property.

Another thing you should change is to remove the Presenter's constructor from `App` and let the `OtherModule` be responsible for that:

```
@Module
public class OtherModule {
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    PresenterClass getPresentationClass(Context ctx) {
        return new PresenterClass(ctx, new ModelManager());
    }
}
```

I recommend you to check this [article](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Dagger/article.html) where it goes deeper on Dagger explanation and even shows another Dagger's version that is directly thought to the Android environment.